# Removing variable names with ggpairs

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggally

I'm trying to produce a specific plot using ggpairs of the GGally package with code like the following:

```
data(tips, package="reshape")
pm <- ggpairs(tips[,1:3], axisLabels="none")
```

My problem is that I can't figure out how to remove the labels "total_bill", "tip", "sex" from the sides of the plot. Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing:

```
 data = tips[,1:3]
 pm <- ggpairs(data)
 g11<-ggally_blank() 

 for(i in 1:ncol(data)) {
     for(j in 1:ncol(data)) {
         if(i<=j) {
             pm <- putPlot(pm, g11, i, j)
         }
     }
 }
```

You get rid of the `axisLabels` from the side of the plot, and **you get a 'blank' graph in the diagonal and upper triangle of the graph** (as requested). In your case, the **"18 columns" would be captured by `ncol(data)` in the loop**. Does that work?

It would look like this:
[image]

Comment: Alas no. This is because I would then like to blank the diagonal and upper triangle of plots with something like: ggpairs(tips[,1:3], upper="blank", diag="blank") but this would leave non-empty diagonal elements

Comment: @user2699676 I have modified the answer to leave a blank diagonal and upper-triangle in the graph. Please look above. Does that do the trick?

Comment: That works but I then have the problem that I'd like to do the same thing for another dataset with 18 variables. That would give me a 18x18 matrix of plots which would require 18(18+1)/2 = 171 such putPlot commands which is doable but not pretty.

Comment: @user2699676 Well, you could easily structure that as a loop. Please refer to my edited answer.

Comment: There might be a more elegant way of doing a similar loop using the `apply` function. If the above isn't efficient with your dataset, you could look into replacing the nested `for loop` with `apply`.

Comment: This seems to work for my application, so thanks Mariam. I'd still be interested to know if there's a way of turning off the labels in ggpairs through a command though if it exists or changing their style.